# Download file in jenkins job

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, amazon-ecs

I have a jenkins job which will execute node application. This job is configured to run on docker only during execution.

Is it possible to download file from node application everytime when job gets executed?

I tried using nodejs plugins to save and download file. File is getting saved in local but not able to download.

Comment: Are you saying that the nodejs application running inside the docker executor is creating a file and you want this file to be available after the job has run?

Comment: Yes, i need to download the file as job output.

Comment: did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If your docker container runs some job and creates a file as the output of the job, and you want it available outside the container after the job is done, my suggestion is that you create the file in a location that is mapped to a host folder via the volume option. Run your docker container as follows:

```
sudo docker -d -v /my/host/folder:/my/location/inside/container mynodeapp:latest
```

Ensure that your node application writes the output file to the location /my/location/inside/container. When the job is completed, the output file can be accessed on the host-machine at /my/host/folder.